# using the 'this' variable within object constructor

Tags: javascript, scope, this

I'm a bit confused on the result I'm getting when calling the 'this' variable inside in object constructor.

```
function Slider(tag){
    this.tag = document.querySelector(tag),
    this.start = function(){
        return this.interval;
    },
    this.interval = setInterval(function(){
        console.log(this.tag); //undefined
        console.log(this); //window object
    }, 2000)
}
var route ={
    init:function(){        
        mySlide = new Slider('slider');
        mySlide.start();
    }
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', route.init);
```

I'm logging tag `console.log(this.tag)` however it's returning `undefined` and when logging the `this` variable inside `console.log(this)` it refers to the window object.

[Here is a Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2whqofx3/1/)

**Question:** Why isn't `console.log(this.tag)` returning the selected element?

Comment: Callback functions don't inherit `this` from the surrounding scope. You can either use `bind` or assign a variable `var self = this;` in the surrounding scope.

Comment: Lexical Scoping, read up on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because when you pass a callback function to `setInterval`, it's called in the global scope.  That's why `this` is `window`.

You can use [`Function.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to set the context of the function to your `this` object and make it work as you want.

```
this.interval = setInterval(function(){
    console.log(this.tag);
}.bind(this), 2000);
```

Also, I just want to point out that `mySlide.start();` does nothing.  When you call `new Slider('slider')`, that's when your interval is set.  Your `mySlide.start();` just returns the intervalID (which is only used for `clearInterval()`).  Actually since you are not even using the return value of `mySlide.start();`, calling it is useless.

UPDATE: Another solution is to use `var self = this;` in your constructor function and then use `self` inside `setInterval()`:

```
function Slider(tag){
    var self = this;

    this.tag = document.querySelector(tag),
    this.interval = setInterval(function(){
        console.log(self.tag);
    }, 2000);
}
```

UPDATE: If you are on a browser that supports ["arrow functions"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), then you can do this:

```
this.interval = setInterval(() => {
    console.log(this.tag);
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Ahhh I nice yeah `bind` works, was just going to say that... so I want to be able to clear the interval, but need to set the `setInterval` to a variable to be able to clear it you know. Is there a better approach you would use to `.start()` and `.clear()`?

Comment: @JordanDavis: I would have `.start()` be the one to call `setInterval()`.  Have `.start()` do `this.interval = setInterval(function(){...});`, that way you can have a `.clear()` do `clearInterval(this.interval);`.  Right now, your `.start()` doesn't actually start anything.

Comment: Awesome your the man! Is that a typical/standard approach to use the `bind` method?

Comment: @JordanDavis: It's one approach, yeah.  It's normal.  Another approach is to do something like `var self = this;` at the very top of your `Slider` function.  Then use `self.tag` inside your `setInterval()`.

Comment: Ok cool, yeah I've seen the `self` method just want to make sure it's like a standard approach to implement. Yeah I use arrow functions all day long, some people don't understand them here so I usually post with normal syntax not fat arrow.

Comment: @JordanDavis: Arrow functions and "normal" functions are actually *different*.  People here may or may not understand them (since they are a newer syntax), but they do different things.  Do not be afraid to post your *real* code here instead of code you modified for this question.  If you were using an arrow function, then your code would've worked as you expected in the first place.

Comment: Oh no I know the scope changes, between the two for `this` variable. I just typically don't do this kind of object creation this way, so just little confused.

Comment: typically I use a JSON syntax and pass it through a traversing `build()` function I wrote which returns the structure html (attributes,events,text) and an traversing 'assemble()` function which does the same but for dynamic data, for like an AJAX response. However things like a slider... or calendar... are pretty much the same everytime.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127747/discussion-between-jordan-davis-and-rocket-hazmat).

Answer (score 1):

The scope of the anonymous function in the `setInterval` is the Window.
If you want it to be the Slider instance, you should [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) it first.

```
function Slider(tag){
this.tag = document.querySelector(tag),
this.start = function(){
    return this.interval;
},
this.interval = setInterval(function(){
    console.log(this.tag); //undefined
    console.log(this); //window object
}.bind(this), 2000)
}
```