# Classes - 'this' vs 'self'

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I'm using the new [ES6 Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) and am having a hard time understanding why I can reference the `this` variable is one of the methods.

//CLASS

```
class Form{ 
    constructor(){
        var self = this;
    }   

    assemble(){
        log(self);
    }
}
```

//CALLED

```
var form = new Form();
form.assemble();
```

//RETURN

```
window object (not the reference to the class object)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using the 'this' variable within object constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40515218/using-the-this-variable-within-object-constructor)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How does the “this” keyword in Javascript act within an object literal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal/13441628#13441628)

Comment: self is an actual, existing property on window: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self  You are redefining it in your constructor as a local variable, temporarily, and then doing nothing with it. In your assemble() method, you are NOT actually referencing that self variable you declared in your constructor, you are referencing window.self.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` isn't a variable. It's more like a hidden argument to functions.

You can't access `self` in your example because it's a local variable within the constructor, so it's not available to your `assemble` method.

You don't need `self` at all for your example, just use `this`:

```
class Form {
    assemble(){
        log(this);             // ***
    }
}
var form = new Form();
form.assemble();
```

If you were passing `form.assemble` to something that wouldn't guarantee to call it with the right `this`, you could define `assemble` as an instance function member instead, by defining it in the constructor; then it would close over `self`. But you don't need `self` for this in ES2015 and above; just use an arrow function, which closes over `this`:

```
class Form {
    constructor(){
        var self = this;
        this.assemble = () => {
            log(this);
        };
    }   
}
var form = new Form();
form.assemble();          // Works
var f = form.assemble;
f();                      // Also works
```

But odds are you don't need to do that.

Comment: Thank you! so simple, just not use to it stuck in my old ways, haha.

Comment: Does defining the function in the constructor have any advantages over defining it as a normal class function and binding it in the constructor, i.e. `this.foo = this.foo.bind(this)`? I personally find the latter to be more readable.

Comment: @Timo: If you use an arrow function like I did above, no, no technical advantage either way, just the style difference. I mean, okay, technically with the `bind` solution there's an extra function (just the one, not one per instance), but who cares? If you use a  `function` function in the constructor instead of an arrow (but why would you? :-) ), then the `bind` solution is better, because you can use `super` in that case but can't from a `function` function created in the constructor.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the clarification!